# How to retain the input file type post data

Tags: php, html, post, file-upload

How can I redirect a page with a file POST data on it? Something like

**Page1.php**

```
<html>
    <form action="page2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

**Page2.php**

```
<html>
    <form action="page3.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file"/> ### get the value of file from page1.php and send to page 3
        <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Just handle it server-side.  Also, this has already been asked here at least 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

Not that way... the file is uploaded when the user submits the form. You could then base64 encode that file and embed it in the HTML as a hidden field to be submitted on the second form, but that's very inefficient.

You should handle the file upload on the first submission. Save the file somewhere or stick it in your database, whichever works better for the files you're receiving. If you save the file, I'd recommend generating a unique name for it (like a UUID). Then use the filename or the primary key from the DB as a value in a hidden field in the second form, which you can use to find the file you already received when the user submits the second form.